# Is it possible to create runmode specific clientlib?

Tags: aem

I am using AEM6.0 SP2. I have an author.css required for stlying for authoring dialogs. I am including the clientlib at template header with condition .

My problem is I have to add this condition in all templates headlib. Is there a way similar to run mode based [osgi config](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/RunModeDependentConfigAndInstall.html), to simply create clientlib-author and OTB automatically excludes the library on publish without wanting the explicit runmode condition on all templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on where you want to use your custom author library, but the most simple way to accomplish this without touching your pages is just to use one of the standard AEM libraries loaded in authoring mode as category for your library, such as "cq.authoring.dialog", "granite.ui.foundation", "cq.authoring.editor", etc. So for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:ClientLibraryFolder"
    categories="[granite.ui.foundation]"
    />
```

I haven't tried to use runmodes with libraries, but I don't think that this is possible. Alternative you could write your own jsp taglib where you can implement such behaviour.

Comment: Yes I think this will help to restrict my library to author only. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so.  You should try to structure your template inheritance so you can put the code in one place (Don't Repeat Yourself - DRY) that is in a super type's JSP, then let the inheriting child templates change the parts that differ.

Comment: Thanks @Shawn. This is my immediate next steps to restructure templates extending a base and reducing repeated codes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can verify your wcm mode in the following way :

```
if (CQ.WCM.getMode() == 'edit') {
    include your lib here
    .........
}
```

Please note, `CQ` object may be undefined on publish

Comment: My problem is I dont want to add this condition since I have quite many isolated templates with no base template. And CQ object is indeed available in publish